# Building a Frequency Table in C using an Array

Tags: c, frequency-analysis

I am trying to read a file of 99 numbers and put them into a frequency table and histogram using an array.  The format is coming out correct, but it is only reading the first number in my file for some reason.  I have only included the beginning of my code through the "get_data" function as my error is invoking my "Too much data" note I wrote into the code.  Please Help!  This is the function code I am using for reading my file:

```
#define MAX_ELMNTS 99
#define ANLYS_RNG 10       

//Function Declarations
int get_data(int numbers[], int size, int range);

void print_data(int numbers[], int size, int line_size);

void make_frequency(int numbers[], int size, int frequency[], int range);

void make_histogram(int frequency[], int range);

int main(void)
{
  //Local Declarations
  int size;
  int nums       [MAX_ELMNTS];
  int frequency  [ANLYS_RNG];

  //Statements
  size = get_data(nums, MAX_ELMNTS, ANLYS_RNG);
  print_data(nums, size, 20);

  make_frequency(nums, size, frequency, ANLYS_RNG);   
  make_histogram(frequency, ANLYS_RNG);

  return 0;
}//end main

int get_data(int data[], int size, int range)
{
  //Local Declarations
  int data_in;
  int loader = 0;
  FILE* fpData;

  //Statements
  range--;
  if(!(fpData = fopen("An00966898.DAT", "r")))
    printf("Error opening file\a\a\n");

  while(loader < size && fscanf(fpData, "%d", &data_in) != EOF)
    if(data_in >= 0 && data_in <= range)
       data[loader++] = data_in;
    else
      printf("\nData point %d invalid. Ignored. \n", data_in);
  if(loader == size)
    printf("Too much data. Process what read.\n");
  return loader;
}//end get_data
```

Comment: What are the values of `loader` and `size` when you get the "Too much data" message?

Comment: My file contains 99 numbers.  values 1-9

Comment: To be honest, I used loader because there was an example in the book that looked like this.

Comment: You want to run your code inside a debugger, tracing it step by step to learn what is *really* going on.

Comment: I was using Xcode on mac, but I couldn't figure out how to open the file so I went back to 'terminal'.

Comment: Your `get_data` function works perfectly well. I would only suggest you check the number of fields converted, instead of `EOF` with `fscanf(fpData, "%d", &data_in) == 1` and also your test `if(loader == size)` should be `if(loader > size)`. You seem uncertain about limits checking, because of the `range--` followed by `data_in <= range` when the simpler `data_in < range` would do.

Comment: `fscanf` is not doing what you think it does. You need to check the return value to see how many items it matched. In other words - you loop condition is wrong.

Comment: @WeatherVane - How can you say `perfectly well` when the code is plain wrong? Not checking the return value calls for all kind of problems.

Comment: @4386427 nor very well phrased then. It worked on my machine with 99 items in a file after correcting the `loader == size` error, and I mentioned another fault.

Comment: OK, I made the adjustments suggested, but for some reason my file still only gets the first number.  Any suggestions?

Comment: @DavidHouse - How does your input file look. Maybe you should investigate what happens to new lines.

Comment: The fault is elsewhere. The code you show does not even output how many data items you read. Sohow do you know? Please show the whole code.

Comment: @4386427 what do you think happens to new lines? My test file had 9 lines of 10 numbers separated by spaces, and 1 line of 9 numbers. `fscanf` with the `%d` format cleans off all preceeding *whitespace*

Comment: I had each number separated by a comma.  Is that wrong?

Comment: That was my Problem!!! Thanks.  I didn't know you couldn't use commas.

Comment: @DavidHouse you can provided you match them in the format string with `"%d,"`